# How to use linux command in subprocess python

Tags: python, linux, unix, subprocess

I have linux command like below:

```
 find /data/*/hr/ -printf "%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n"
```

How do i use in python subprocess check_output

I have tried like below but not working

```
 file_name = "/data/*/%s/" % (filename)
 get_perm = check_output(["find", file_name, "-printf", '\"%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n\"'])
```

Error I am getting:

```html
find: ‘/data/*/hr/’: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "handover.py", line 90, in <module>
    get_perm = check_output(["find", file_name, "-printf", '\"%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n\"'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['find', '/data/*/hr/', '-printf', '"%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `-printf`

Comment: Do you get any output? Do you get an error (i.e. a `CalledProcessError`?). If it dumped because it didn't like the `-printf"%f: %p:...` argument, it should have raised something

Comment: Python is also translating `\n` in the string into a literal newline, which might be strange when `find` gets it. You can also avoid escaping `"` chars by using `'` chars to wrap the string literal in.

Comment: Edited Post and provide output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 2):

Finally,

I found below method

```
cmd = "find /data/*/{}/* -printf \"%f:%p:%u:%g:%m\n\"".format(filename)
info = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
print info.stdout.read()
```

This solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the specified file does not exist. If you run the command directly in a shell, you will get the same response.

For example, the following works as expected:

```
import subprocess
import os

file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.txt')
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello world')

get_perm = subprocess.check_output([
    "find",
     file_name,
     "-printf",
    '"%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n"'
    ], shell=True)

print(get_perm)
os.remove(file_name)
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> If the return code [from subprocess.check_output]  was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

I recommend you wrap your check_output call in a try..except, and catch the CalledProcessError.

Alternatively, if you really don't want to deal with the exception, you could instead execute the command:

`x=$(find ~/data/*/hr/ -printf "%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n" 2>/dev/null || true) && echo $x`

This will never return nonzero and will only ever contain output if the file exists.

**Edit**
As Michael pointed out, the '*' is not getting expanded. However, if you set `shell=True`, it will. Try modifying your command as follows:

```
 file_name = "/data/*/%s/" % (filename)
 get_perm = check_output(["find", file_name, "-printf", '"%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n"'], shell=True)
```

Comment: While it's true that the file isn't found, the problem is likely that the `*` in the path should be expanded.

Comment: @MichaelMior Good catch. If you set `shell=True`, it will expand that the splat.

Comment: You're right. Adding `shell=True` is an easy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Your shell will expand the `*` in `/data/*/hr/` when you call on the command line. Calling the function directly via `check_output` causes find to look for literally the directory `/data/*/hr/`. You could use the `glob` module to expand the path before passing to `find`:

```
import glob

file_name = "/data/*/%s/" % (filename)
get_perm = check_output(["find"] + glob.glob(file_name) + ["-printf", '\"%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n\"'])
```

[`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) simply produces an array of path names which match the given expression by expanding any `*`s and some other special characters.

Comment: Hi Michael, It works fine.. But problem is filename "/data/*/fin/" . If fin does not exist. It will list other values. If fin does not exit. I  expect to get no such file or directory error

Comment: @gopinara It will list other files because you have a trailing slash, which the `find` command interprets as you indicating you want to list all of the files/directories contained within /fin/. Try removing the trailing slash. You can also specify a type to find to limit the results to only files or directories, like, `find /data/*/fin -type f`. Also, the first argument to find is usually the directory which you want to search within for a file or directory. Maybe you want something like `find /data/*/fin -type f -name your_file_name.ext`

Comment: I tried removing slash and adding -type d..same result

Comment: You may just want to check if `glob.glob(file_name)` produces an empty array and if so, don't run the command at all.